# Telegram Bot response based on format in files

Tags: python, google-app-engine, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm new with python and want to learn by creating telegram bot using google apps engine. I'm using this repository project https://github.com/yukuku/telebot for my bot foundation. In this project main.py, we can find this code:

```
if text.startswith('/'):
            if text == '/start':
                reply('Bot enabled')
                setEnabled(chat_id, True)
            elif text == '/stop':
                reply('Bot disabled')
                setEnabled(chat_id, False)
            elif text == '/image':
                img = Image.new('RGB', (512, 512))
                base = random.randint(0, 16777216)
                pixels = [base+i*j for i in range(512) for j in range(512)]  # generate sample image
                img.putdata(pixels)
                output = StringIO.StringIO()
                img.save(output, 'JPEG')
                reply(img=output.getvalue())
            else:
                reply("What command")

        # CUSTOMIZE FROM HERE
        elif 'who are you' in text:
            reply('telebot starter kit, created by yukuku: https://github.com/yukuku/telebot')
        elif 'what time' in text:
            reply('look at the top-right corner of your screen!')
        else:
            if getEnabled(chat_id):
                try:
                    resp1 = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://www.simsimi.com/requestChat?lc=en&ft=1.0&req=' + urllib.quote_plus(text.encode('utf-8'))))
                    back = resp1.get('res').get('msg')
                except urllib2.HTTPError, err:
                    logging.error(err)
                    back = str(err)
                if not back:
                    reply('okay...')
                elif 'I HAVE NO RESPONSE' in back:
                    reply('you said something with no meaning')
                else:
                    reply(back)
            else:
                logging.info('not enabled for chat_id {}'.format(chat_id))
```

However, I want to use textfile to enrich my bot knowledge instead of hardcode. The textfile will be like this:

```
/fact1#I'm a robot
/fact2#I'm not human
/fact3#Stop talking to me
```

...etc

I've tried using code like this:

```
d = {}
with open("data.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split("#")
        d[key] = val

for x in d.keys():
    if text==x:
        reply(d[x])
```

But something is off and the bot stop replying. Please help me solve this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried checking the log output for any errors?

Comment: I've checked it and no error in log

Comment: There could be an issue with the newlines included from the file, you could try d[key] = val[:-1] to trim them (the last line in the file should have a newline added to avoid chopping off the last character).